# What Sharepoint permission level is needed to sync with MS Project (not Project Server)?

Tags: sharepoint-online, ms-project

I am researching syncing Sharepoint with MS Project for my boss. Does anyone know what permissions are needed for Sharepoint (or MS Project) in order to sync properly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It was my understanding that EDIT perm level was the minimum necessary to make revisions, etc.  READ level, otherwise.